# How do I reset a specific part of a state with onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an application that when a user clicks a button it loads a data set. When another button is clicked, a different data set loads. I am trying to clear the data set each time a button is clicked. So if I click button 2, the state for button 1 is reset to `[]` (the data is an array)

Here is my code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  handleCopyTrack = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ courthouse: [] });

    let args = {
      selected_site_id: this.props.authenticate.selected_site_id,
      site_name: this.props.authenticate.site_name,
      sec_organization_id: this.props.authenticate.selected_sec_organization_id,
      sec_user_name: this.props.authenticate.sec_user_name,
    };
    this.props.loadCopyTrackInfo(args);
  };

  handleCourtHouse = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ copytrack: [] });

    let args = {
      selected_site_id: this.props.authenticate.selected_site_id,
      site_name: this.props.authenticate.site_name,
      sec_organization_id: this.props.authenticate.selected_sec_organization_id,
      sec_user_name: this.props.authenticate.sec_user_name,
    };
    this.props.loadCourtHouseInfo(args);
  };
```

This part doesn't work: `this.setState({ courthouse: [] })`;

What am I missing?

Comment: What is not working? What's happening instead? Where is it used? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: The states aren't being updated (set to empty arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your state's initialization. Do you hava a constructor?

Also setState is an async function.
If you want to change a state and then use that state with changed value, you have to call an other function in setState's callback.

```
const handleClick = this.setState({ courthouse: [] }, this.handleClickButtonOperations());
```

Comment: While it's true that `setState` is async, it returns nothing, so I'm not sure where you're going with `handleClick` here? And since OP hasn't demonstrated that he is using the state in the click handlers (he's only resetting part of it), then there's no need to use `setState` callback.

Comment: And you're calling the function instead of passing it as a callback to `this.setState`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

I set local state:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  showCopytrack: false,
  showCourtHouse: false,
};
```

}

Then when an event is called, I update the alternating state:

```
  handleCopyTrack = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ showCopytrack: true });
  this.setState({ showCourtHouse: false });
```

Then I show or hide based on what is set to true or false:

```
{this.state.showCopytrack === true ? (
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend switching to hooks:

```
const Home = ({authenticate, loadCopyTrackInfo, loadCourtHouseInfo}) => {
  const [courtHouse, setCourtHouse] = useState([]);
  const [copyTrack, setCopyTrack] = useState([]);

  function handleCopyTrack(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Why you even need to clear this array here? Initial state will be empty array so after click new data will be added so no need to clearing
    //setCourtHouse([]);

    //you can pass here authenticate object
    return loadCopyTrackInfo(authenticate);
  };

  function handleCourtHouse(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //setCopyTrack([]);

    return loadCourtHouseInfo(authenticate);
  };
```

Comment: Hooks versus class component is irrelevant here. And [state updates are merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) in class component.